# Not able to update octave

Tags: fedora, upgrade, octave

As per Wiki page of GNU software octave latest version is 4.2.1 (Released in february 2017). 
I am using fedora 25 and the octave in my system is version 4.0.3 .

I tried upgrading it to the latest version by using both

`dnf upgrade octave`

and

`dnf update octave`

but both showed

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:29:36 ago on Sat Sep 23 16:02:26 2017.

Dependencies resolved.

Nothing to do.

Complete!
```

Why am I not able to update to latest version, is it because fedora 25 doesn't support latest octave version? or any other reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the GNU Octave website.

> Executable versions of GNU Octave for GNU/Linux systems are provided
>   by the individual distributions. Distributions known to package Octave
>   include Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, Gentoo, and openSUSE. These packages
>   are created by volunteers. The delay between an Octave source release
>   and the availability of a package for a particular GNU/Linux
>   distribution varies.

So most likely the volunteers did not catch up with the latest version of Octave.

Also not sure if that package will get an update on Fedora 25. Browsing the repository for Fedora 26 reveals that version 4.2.1 is available for Fedora 26. So you might consider upgrading to Fedora 26.

You also can download the sources and compile Octave on your own. But I would rather tend to upgrade Fedora.

Comment: @srk_cb Or you could backpor the package from the more recent version of Fedora. I don't; use RPM based distributions, but it's probably a matter of rebuilding the source RPM on your system. Maybe adjusting the dependencies.